# Keywords extraction from each paragraph of an article using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, text-extraction

I want to extract 3-4 keywords from each paragraph of an article using python. 
I have used Rake NLTK toolkit but it extracts keywords from whole article not from each paragraph.

I have used this code:

```
from rake_nltk import Rake
import os
r = Rake()
Data = open('input.txt','r')
text = Data.read()

r.extract_keywords_from_text(text)
a = r.get_ranked_phrases()

str = ""
for i in a:
    str += i
    str += " "

str = str[:-1]
print(str)
```

But this extracts keywords from whole text file not from each paragraph separately.

Example (Required):
1st para }-- *(car, red, bike) **keywords***
2nd para }-- *(crash, car, bike) **keywords***
3red para }-- *(police, ambulance) **keywords***

Comment: Why don't you split your text in paragraphs and apply `extract_keywords_from_text()` for each paragraph instead?

Comment: Okay can you help me in that. I want to limit my keywords selection to 3-4 words per paragraph.

Comment: Can you please show `input.txt`- the answer would depend on that? It could be as simple as `text.split('\n')`

Comment: But how to run my code for each paragraphs ?